# It seemed it's gonna take forever

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, synonyms

Let's say you are storytelling your BBQ purchase which you had wasted so much time waiting in line. And you say:

> 1) Sometimes the line would move fast, like when a bunch of meat was cooked, but other times, it just **seemed to take forever**.

In comparison with:

> 2) Sometimes the line would move fast, like when a bunch of meat was cooked, but other times, it just **seemed it would take forever**.

Is the second sentence grammatical? And synonymous with #1?

Comment: The way I see it, both are grammatical and express the same idea.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting... coz' I thought the first one is ungrammatical and it winds me up a bit, like it doesn't sound good to ear, weird, so to speak.

Comment: The first one is ***slightly*** awkward because “it” feels like it means the whole experience of queuing, which you could only reflect on *after* the experience; it would be more appropriate if you were talking about multiple occasions. So not quite synonymous, no.

Comment: @J.R. same idea, but both are not correct in the context (you can fix by adding e.g. *… to move again* on the end).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are fine.  The first simply relates an *interminable* experience.  For example:

> **It seemed to take forever** to get past the border checkpoint, but on the other side traffic opened up and they made good time driving to their destination.

Adding "would" can suggest the expectation was different from the result:

> It seemed it **would** take forever to get to the front of the line, **but then** several more registers opened and we got out with our purchases in a matter of minutes.

Comment: True, but *seemed* can also imply that the reality was different :o)

Comment: @WillCrawford  yes, that's true.  I'm just trying to highlight the minimal contrast between the two sentences.

Comment: Yes, that's a hobby of mine, too :o)